# How to rearrange nested array by the same key's property

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Is there a way in D3.JS or javascript/jquery to do this:

I have an array of arrays..

```
[
 [{date:x,data:1},{date:y,data:5},{date:z,data:2}],
 [{date:x,data:9},{date:y,data:10}],
 [{date:y,data:8},{date:z,data:5}]
]
```

And I want to rearrange them so that the arrays within this top-level array all have the same date:

```
[
 [{date:x,data:1},{date:x,data:9}],
 [{date:y,data:5},{date:y,data:10},{date:y,data:8}],
 [{date:z,data:2},{date:z,data:5}]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy with d3:

```js
xs = [
    [{date: 'x', data: 1}, {date: 'y', data: 5}, {date: 'z', data: 2}],
    [{date: 'x', data: 9}, {date: 'y', data: 10}],
    [{date: 'y', data: 8}, {date: 'z', data: 5}]
]

z = d3.nest()
    .key(x => x.date)
    .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
    .entries(d3.merge(xs))
    .map(x => x.values)


z.map(e => document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(e)+'</pre>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript

```
var x = 'x', y = 'y', z = 'z';
var arr = [
  [{ date: x, data: 1 }, { date: y, data: 5 }, { date: z, data: 2 }],
  [{ date: x, data: 9 }, { date: y, data: 10 }],
  [{ date: y, data: 8 }, { date: z, data: 5 }]
];
var res = arr.reduce(function (result, inArr, index) {
  inArr.forEach(function (obj) {
    result[obj.date] = result[obj.date] || [];
    result[obj.date].push(obj);
  });
  return result;
}, {});

var output = [];
for (var key in res) {
  output.push(res[key]);
}
console.log(output);
```

will output

```
[
 [
  {
   "date": "x",
   "data": 1
  },
  {
   "date": "x",
   "data": 9
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "date": "y",
   "data": 5
  },
  {
   "date": "y",
   "data": 10
  },
  {
   "date": "y",
   "data": 8
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "date": "z",
   "data": 2
  },
  {
   "date": "z",
   "data": 5
  }
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without any lib:

1) Create a map with key `date`

2) group by key

3) create resultset

4) done

```
arr=[
 [{date:'x',data:1},{date:'y',data:5},{date:'z',data:2}],
 [{date:'x',data:9},{date:'y',data:10}],
 [{date:'y',data:8},{date:'z',data:5}]
]

function group(a){
    return arr.reduce(function(o,n){
    n.forEach(function(a){
        var key=a.date;
      if(!o[key]) o[key]=[];
      var tmp=o[key];
      tmp.push(a);
      o[key]=tmp;
    });
    return o;
  },{});
}

var resultMap = group(arr);
var result = Object.keys(resultMap).map(
    function(x){
    return resultMap[x];
  }
);
console.log(result)
```

Here the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buj17ae4/).

`Array.prototype.reduce()`is explained[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

`Array.prototype.map()`is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)